# Why isn't User considered in the Role MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, roles, membership-provider

I am using the standard membership tables and login. However, for some reason when the user log's in. They don't have a role. I want to be able to redirect to a page, if the user is in role, like so:

```
if (User.IsInRole("TestRole"))
    RedirectToAction("Index", "MyController", new { area = "TestArea" });
```

this fails and while debugging it appears that the user has no role. If, after logging in, I go directly to the page which has the Authorize attribute. It works.

If I use this code:

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole(model.UserName, "TestRole"))
    RedirectToAction("Index", "MyController", new { area = "TestArea" });
```

It will work, but it's kind of not for the current logged in user. Technically it is, but I should be able to redirect based on if they're in a role. I fear that if I don't fix this now, I'll have a lot of issues later. (role based menu's, etc.)

Any help or suggestions where I could look would be awesome. I've done this stuff before and am stumped at what could cause this.

Note: if I use an admin panel, I can tell the user is considered logged in by the system (database wise)